# index page display record from child class

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a standard scaffold named cities.  Each city has_many images.
On the index page of cities, how can I show only the first image record associated with it?

```
  def index
   @cities = City.all
  end


  <% @cities.each do |city| %>
   <% city.images.each do |image| %>
```

The code in my view will show all the images for a given city and repeat the same city record based on the number of images.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
city.images.first
```

This will get you the first image or `nil` if the collection is empty.